# Searock Castle - complete level only with Zoya

Tags: trine-2

[image]

I've managed to get up to the part shown in the image, but I couldn't find any way to get past it using only one Zoya.
The part described at the image is almost the end of the level. I need to find a way to blow that balloon at the top right so I can climb upwards. I couldn't find a way to do it without Amadeus.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you are asking?

Comment: I was trying not to share too much to prevent people from getting stuck on the same ideas I have, but I will edit to give a little bit more info.

Comment: Why do you want to complete that level only using Zoya?

Comment: its part of completing the entire game with only one character achievement. I chose Zoya.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this counts for each level separately, so each level has to be completed by using only one character, but you can use different characters for different levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nearly impossible. A friend and I just tried it and we didn't see any way to complete this level with only one character, no matter if Zoya, Amadeus or Pontius.

[This video](http://youtu.be/NE0VfPyTsOs) shows a very, very advanced tactic. I wasn't able to do it myself.
He basically uses the gravity arrow to get one of the barrels from the left to the right by continuously shooting gravity arrows at it. He then levitates it upwards and uses the hook on it.

But the good question that kotekzot already asked: *Why* do you want to do that? The achievement you're talking about is

> **Trine Kaput For Good?**
>
> Complete each **expansion** level using only one character

Searock Castle is not an expansion level, so you don't need to solo it.

Comment: Thanks, the tactic shown in the video is exactly what I tried to do. But I thought there might be a better way since almost always the environment allows a way for one character to get through it alone. At least I know it is possible though.